# MQTT TOPIC Fetches a single character

Tags: mqtt

My Publish topic -> "abc/123/#"

Try Subscribe topic -> "a"  "abc"  "abc/123"  "123"  "b"  "c"  "1"  "2"  "3" 
Why can I get all of those topic Publish content?!

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here, I've made my best guess, but you really need to add a lot more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can not publish to a wildcard topic

You can only use wildcards in subscriptions